# Graph API Office 365 usage report - Forbidden

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I try to use Office 365 usage reports in Graph API. I would like for example export the EmailActivity report with the request GET /reports/EmailActivity(view=view-value, period=period-value, date=date-value)/content

When I try the example https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/EmailActivity(view='Detail',period='D7')/content in Graph Explorer I have the following error

Failure - Status Code 403705msLooks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Invalid scope claims/roles.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "f1f89dcf-b2df-4537-a4ad-f07ccfff2899",
            "date": "2017-07-05T17:01:23"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't uderstand because I looging like an admin of Office 365 I have add almost all the permision. What I had miss ?

Edit : More details,
I use Graph Explorer, when I click to grant access 
[image]

I have th confirmation

[image]

I've the admin right

[image]

I try my request in graph explorer

[image]

And I have my error

[image]

I don't know what I could do be better.

Comment: Could you provide the scopes you're requesting?

Comment: Where I could found m scope in graph explorer request ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Get EmailActivity report document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/reportroot_emailactivity) , read that report needs `Reports.Read.All` permission . And according to [Reports permissions of microsoft graph api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#reports-permissions), `Reports.Read.All` is `application permission`which allows an app to read all service usage reports without a signed-in user. To call that api , you need to use client credential flow to acquire token with app identity :

1. Add `Read all usage reports` application permission of microsoft graph in your azure ad application :
   [image]
2. Grant that application permission by clicking `Grant Permissions` button in above screenshot with admin account of your AAD .
3. Using client credential flow to acquire access token for microsoft graph :

   ```
   POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/chencl.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token

   grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F
   ```

   After you get the access token , you could decode the token using [online tool](http://jwt.calebb.net/), you should find `Reports.Read.All` in `roles` claim .
4. Then you could call the EmailActivity api , it returns 302 Found response redirecting to a pre-authenticated download URL for the report:[image]

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I have edit my post with more detail, because my error appear in the graph explorer

Comment: graph explorer is used for testing , and it doesn't includes that permission(which need app identity) .

Comment: One note, Reports.Read was added to Explorer very recently but hasn't hit production yet. You can however run it locally via Node. See https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer for info on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Application Registration Portal to get the token:

1. In Application Registration Portal set the permission that you need, for example
   Mail.Read and **Directory.AccessAsUser.All**. Always you need use **Directory.AccessAsUser.All** if you want get the token

   2. When save Application Registration Portal go to Azure Portal, in Azure Active Directory --> Enterprise applications --> click in you application --> "click in consent permission for username..." --> login --> accept.
   3. Use library as hellojs and get a token.