# Accessing Usage Reports via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to take advantage of the public preview of Microsoft Graph reporting APIs for retrieving Office 365 product usage data.  I have an application registered for Graph that successfully executes Graph calls for non-reporting APIs (i.e. the access_token I generate with my app is successfully used to access users information for a tenant: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users) but when I try any of the report resources I encounter the below error:

> Invalid scope claims/roles.

According to the documentation I've read this would seem to imply that my app does not have the necessary permissions for reports but this is not correct as I have confirmed that the app has the "Read all usage reports" application permission enabled.

Has anyone else encountered similar challenges with the Microsoft Graph reporting APIs and have any suggestions that I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added this scope after you had already authorized the application, it may still be using the previous/cached list of scopes. You can force re-authorization by adding [?prompt=consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code) to your initial authorization URL. For example:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id={app id}
&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect uri}&prompt=consent`

Comment: I was pretty sure that the scope was not changed after the app was authorized but I tried forcing the re-authorization anyway and I still encounter the "Invalid scope claims/roles." error after.

Comment: Have you completed the Admin Consent process? If not, this would prevent authorizing `Reports.Read.All` for any non-admin users. This isn't the error I would expect to see but I wanted to confirm just in case.

Comment: In the Azure portal I did click Grant Permissions for the app.

Comment: After reading the response to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932155/graph-api-office-365-usage-report-forbidden I inspected the JWT I'm generating.  I found that there is no roles claim at all.  I checked my app's manifest and found an empty appRoles property.  How do app roles get added here?  If manual, what steps should be taken to get the role claim added so it is a part of the access token?

Comment: Did you follow [this process](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)? It sounds like you missed a step when selecting permissions.

Comment: I'll double check the configuration but I noticed there is documentation that refers to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ to register an app then there is other documentation that refers to app registration at https://portal.azure.com/.  Which is the correct place to start?

Comment: Both are valid. The docs I referenced are for the v2 Endpoint. The Azure portal is used for the older endpoint (aka v1 Endpoint). I would recommend using v2 unless you have a very specific need for v1.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to configure a single tenant app to access the reports.